# esc_sql breaks line return escaping

Tags: php, wordpress, escaping

I need to create a new post based on data from an RSS file.

First, I normalize line breaks sequences based on OS type for post content:
`$post_content = str_replace(array ("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), PHP_EOL, $post_content);`

To prepare resulting text for inserting to the database I use the WordPress function `esc_sql`:
`post_content = str_replace( array( '<![CDATA[', ']]>'), '', esc_sql( trim( $post_content[1] ) ) );`

But, it removes char escaping "\" for all line break sequences.

So, instead of this text:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

I got this: (line breaking "\n" sequencing replaced by "n" letter):

```
Line 1.nLine2.
```

I found only this solution: replace `PHP_EOL` with `<br />` tag but I'm not sure it's the best option:
`$post_content = str_replace(array ("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), "<br />", $post_content);`

Maybe there is some alternative for `esc_sql` function?

Comment: _"based on OS type"_ makes little sense to begin with in that context. Replace them all with `\n`.

Comment: _"Maybe there is some alternative for esc_sql function?"_ - [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/) states that _"`$wpdb->prepare()` is generally preferred"_

Comment: @CBroe PHP_EOL is a constant, for Linux it is `\n`, so after replacing nothing has changed.

Comment: I am aware of what it is, I just don't see how using it would make much sense for content you are writing into the database.

Comment: Found this post for `$wpdb->prepare()`: [Safely Escaping Variables In SQL Queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/397855/why-line-returns-are-not-reapply-after-doing-esc-sql). Apparently, I have to make my own custom database query, which looks like an unreasonably complicated option. It always seemed to me that one "magic" function is enough.

Comment: What are you currently using then, to insert this into the database?

Comment: @CBroe `wp_insert_post($post);`. As the [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#security) syas, this function itself handles all necessary sanitization and validation (kses, etc.). So, I guess in this case I can just remove `esc_sql()` and all be securely and fine